# UPDATE query in small tables taking forever

Tags: update, postgresql-9.6

I'm having trouble creating a UPDATE query to perform the following:

I have two tables, `ed` is a 11k rows table with areas from multiple constructions and a key `lote_key` wich links to the table `unid`, wich has 7k rows.

For each row in `unid` I have one or multiple correspondent rows in `ed` and what I want is to sum the areas of each construction and put them in a column `area_const` in `unid`

The code I wrote is the following:

```sql
UPDATE data.unid SET
    area_const = calc.area
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT ed.lote_key, SUM(ST_Area(ed.geom)) AS area
        FROM data.ed
        GROUP BY ed.lote_key
    ) AS calc
    WHERE unid.lote_key = calc.lote_key
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but the query is taking forever to perform, and by forever i mean that I haven't seen it through yet, I need this to be a trigger function so I can't have this code taking that long.

I ran a `EXPLAIN` to see the costs of the operation and it seems ordinary, as follows:

PS: I'm not able to post a `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` since the query has not been completed so far

```
    "Update on unid un  (cost=1531.07..1773.16 rows=5498 width=463)"
"  ->  Hash Join  (cost=1531.07..1773.16 rows=5498 width=463)"
"        Hash Cond: ((calc.lote_key)::text = (un.lote_key)::text)"
"        ->  Subquery Scan on calc  (cost=953.08..1026.10 rows=3651 width=72)"
"              ->  HashAggregate  (cost=953.08..989.59 rows=3651 width=24)"
"                    Group Key: ed.lote_key"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on ed ed  (cost=0.00..605.77 rows=11577 width=179)"
"        ->  Hash  (cost=488.55..488.55 rows=7155 width=407)"
"              ->  Seq Scan on unid un  (cost=0.00..488.55 rows=7155 width=407)"
```

I have another UPDATE code in my db with costs like this one that goes just fine, that got me thinking my mistake was logical or something

If I run only the select part, it goes just fine

Comment: I would like very much to do so, however, the query has been running for 30 minutes by now, let's see

Comment: Are you sure the UPDATE is not waiting for a lock? Check `pg_stat_activity`

Comment: I didn't even knew what a lock was. I had setup a trigger to calculate another field wich apparently was blocking update querys in this table. After I droped it, the query went just fine. Now I think I have another problem, how to set two triggers operating in my database without one blocking the other.